# HeaderForeground

Tags: visual-studio-code

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Интересует как поменять цвет в заголовке но в состоянии неактивном а vs code.
Имею ввиду когда нажимаем параметры появляется окно где удкт разные темы
Есть команда которая изменяет цвет, только когда надат заголовок:
"settings.headerForeground", а мне нужно поменять цвет на заголовке который неактивен,
Т.е команда должна быть на подобии:
"settings.inactiveheaferBackground", подскажите коианду для изменения цвета в неактивном заголовке.В обычном он виде в виде белого цвета.

Comment: ты хочешь поменять цвет окна vscode?

Comment: судя по всему такой [настройки](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#settings-editor-colors) нет

Comment: Хочу поменять цвет заголовка, когда ставишь цвет редактора белым, то заголовков в параметрах не видно что написано, там цвет такой светло серый .Вот и хочу изменить.

Answer (score 0):

За цвет текста выпадающего списка в Settings (настройках) отвечает параметр цвета дефолтного шрифта:

```
"foreground": "#0FFF50",
```

То есть при изменении цвет поменяется не только там, но и в других местах.
Вот, что получается у меня (картинка), если сделать дефолтный цвет зелёным, а settings.headerForeground красным:

```
"foreground": "#0FFF50",
"settings.headerForeground": "#EF5350",
```

Какого-то отдельного параметра для этого объекта я не нахожу.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Приложил фото, вот на светлом фоне плохо шрифт мало просвечивающий, потому что заголовки неактивные цвет белый или серый по умолчанию.Т.е когда выделили заголовок он как у меня, но если посмотреть под ним заголовки они блеклые

Comment: OK Теперь точно понятно. Посмотрю, что и как можно сделать.

Comment: Изменил ответ вверху, посмотрите.

Comment: Красота, то что надо.Спасибо.

Comment: Пожалуйста! Рад, что помог.